# What is $\frac{\delta (\partial_\kappa \sqrt{g})}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

Title says it all, is there a closed expression for

$$\frac{\delta (\partial_\kappa \sqrt{g})}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$$

where $g = \det g_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: I think I saw something similar when reading about variational derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative and the variation actually commute, so you have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\delta\left(\partial_k\sqrt{g}\right)}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}&=\partial_k\frac{\delta\sqrt{g}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}   \\
   &=\partial_k\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta g}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\right)   \\
   &=-\partial_k\left(\frac{g}{2\sqrt{g}}g_{\mu\nu}\right)   \\
   &=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_k\left(\sqrt{g}g_{\mu\nu}\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

For more details, take a look at Carroll's book (section 4.3).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why do you say that the derivative and variation commutes ?
I thought that this was not the case and that it is exactly the reason why a Gibbons-Hawking term was introduced ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the procedure you are mentioning, I was just assuming that they commute since that has been the case in every example I have seen. Why shouldn't they commute?

Comment: I thought about it a bit more. 
They don't commute because you are variating towards the space and deriving towards space.
(contrary to applications in quantum field theory where you variate towards some field and derive towards spacetime)